# mv: missing destination file operand when special characters are involved

Tags: bash, cp, mv, special-characters, filename

This one's silly. I saved my vim session with `:Obsess -S Session.vim` instead of `:Obsess Session.vim`, so now I have a `-S/ Session.vim` file in my project and can't open it with vim as the following is thrown

```
$ vim \-S\ Session.vim 
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled May 23 2020 22:02:57)
Garbage after option argument: "-S Session.vim"
```

Attempting to mv or cp the session file results in similar errors

```
$ mv \-S\ Session.vim Session.vim  
mv: missing destination file operand after 'Session.vim'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
```

```
$ mv '"-S Session.vim"' Session.vim 
mv: cannot stat '"-S Session.vim"': No such file or directory
```

```
$ cp \-S\ Session.vim Session.vim                                                                                                                                                                                 
cp: missing destination file operand after 'Session.vim'                                                                                                                                                                                      
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

Comment: If the filename actually is `-S Session.vim`, then `mv './-S Session.vim' Session.vim` or `mv -- '-S Session.vim' Session.vim`